# Function to find if a value is greater than all prior values in a vector

Tags: r

This should be very simple, but my r knowledge is limited.
I'm trying to find out if any value is greater than all previous values. 
An example would be

```
x<-c(1.1, 2.5, 2.4, 3.6, 3.2)
```

results:

> ```
> NA  True False True False
> ```

My real values are measurements with many decimal places so I doubt I will get the same value twice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `cummax()` to get the biggest value so far. `x >= cummax(x)` basically gives you the answer, although element 1 is `TRUE`, so you just need to change that:

```
> out = x >= cummax(x)
> out[1] = NA
> out
[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I've never seen cummax! You are a saviour. I've been trying all these for loops to no avail. (if anyone has one out of interest I would love to se it.)

Answer (score 1):

Although @Marius has got this absolutely correct. Here is an option with a loop

```
sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) all(x[i] >= x[seq_len(i)]))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or same logic with explicit `for` loop

```
out <- logical(length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)) {
   out[i] <- all(x[i] >= x[seq_len(i)])
}
out[1] <- NA
out
#[1]    NA  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`

```
unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) all(x[i] >=x[seq(i)])))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or with `max.col`

```
max.col(t(sapply(x, `>=`, x)), 'last') > seq_along(x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

or with `for` loop

```
mx <- x[1]
i1 <- logical(length(x))
for(i in seq_along(x)) {i1[i][x[i] > mx] <- TRUE; mx <- max(c(mx, x[i]))}
```